# CSS/HTML: input bar width and button width not the same even though I'm setting it as the same

Tags: html, css

My assignment is to make a login page, and the inputs and buttons have to have a 320px width, including a 2px border and 15px padding. I create two classes for the inputs and button, and in CSS I am specifying these widths for both but the button keeps coming out shorter. Right now it's coming out like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3a1q.png)

I'm fairly new at this so I apologize if my code is messy/this might seem like a silly question.

Here's my code: 
HTML

```
<form class="signup" action="/signup/" method ="post">
 <fieldset name="sign-up">
   <legend>Sign up</legend>

   <div class="input">
   <label for="email">Email</label></br>
   <input class="inputbar" placeholder="foo@bar.com" type="email" name="email" id="email" required/></br>

   <label for="password">Password</label></br>
   <input class="inputbar" placeholder="1234passw0rd" type="password" name="password" id"password" required/></br>
   </div>
</fieldset>

<button type="signupbutton">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.signup {
width: 320px;
padding: 40px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
}

.signup fieldset{
border: none;
}

.input{
text-align: left;
}

.inputbar, button{
border: 2px solid lightgrey;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 15px;
width: 250px;
}

button{
background-color: mediumseagreen;
color: white;
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It's best to set the container width and then the elments inside to 100%. Using `box-sizing: border-box;` is key here.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.signup {
width: 320px;
padding: 40px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
}

.signup fieldset{
border: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.input{
text-align: left;
}

.inputbar, button{
border: 2px solid lightgrey;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 15px;
width: 100%;
}

button{
background-color: mediumseagreen;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: Try to add some additional links/explanation for the OP to read. She obviously didn't know about CSS box model (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) and box-sizing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). The solution helps short term, but knowledge helps in the long run.

Comment: This worked! Can you explain what the * means though? I know it has something to do with having all elements look the same for all types of browsers, but how did this is solve the width problem?

Comment: @Farah Certainly. `*` is a universal selector. It means, select everything. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors

Answer (score 0):

```
.inputbar, button{
border: 2px solid lightgrey;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 15px;
width: 250px;
}
```

It appears you have set the width of the button to 250px. Try changing that to 320px.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the text align on th input class

```
.input{ 
 text-align: left;
}
```

and do this

```
.signup .input label {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Aside that the everything is working alright in chrome

what browser are you using to run your test?

this is whati have on my browser [image: click here]

Comment: Hmm I'm using chrome too. I did what you said and it didn't change anything.